# How to make an executable jar file with JavaFX, Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx

I have a JavaFx project, Spring boot, everything works fine in IDEA. I need to get a startup file from this project. I tried to do it through Project Structure -> Artifacts, but the resulting file does not open.
I learned about the second method through mvn clean, package, spring-boot:repackage, but at the plugin stage, spring-boot:repackage gives an error Source file must not be null.
I am suffering with getting an executable file for 3 days in a row, I don’t know what to do anymore, please help.

JDK - 17.0.5
JAVAFX SDK - 20
JFOENIX - 9.0.10

github project https://github.com/Hooolll/demoz

Comment: You can read the documentation of https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ Inside you can find `Runtime images` and for example `Modular with Maven`. I managed to make mine projects working with Jlink. You can search for example in internet. One article: https://dev.to/cherrychain/javafx-jlink-and-jpackage-h9 I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

By checking github code link. I have found out few things in the pom.xml

The code having compilation issue as its missing `jfoenix` dependency. Also, `javafx-maven-plugin` plugin defined multiple times. Merge configuration and executions at same plugin. Also mainClass configured in executions is not exists it must be `com.jdc.pos.App`

In configuration `application.yml` file you missing `database-platform` configuration.

application.yml file

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kursovayaa
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: pass
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
```

Updated pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demoz</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demoz</name>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <openjfx.version>19.0.2.1</openjfx.version>
    <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>
    <start-class>com.jdc.pos.App</start-class>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
      <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
      <version>${openjfx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
      <version>11.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
      <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
      <version>11.5.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.synedra</groupId>
      <artifactId>validatorfx</artifactId>
      <version>0.3.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
      <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
      <version>12.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
      <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
      <version>17.1.9</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.almasb</groupId>
      <artifactId>fxgl</artifactId>
      <version>17.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.24</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <attach>false</attach>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.jdc.pos.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>assemble-all</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.jdc.pos.App</mainClass>
              <launcher>app</launcher>
              <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
              <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
              <noManPages>true</noManPages>
              <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
              <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

After doing above changes I can able to launch application using `mvn clean javafx:run` command and it shows login window.